# Is having a good yearly GPA (over 3.0) for 2 years useful for Masters even if my overall GPA is low (under 3.0)

Tags: masters, application, gpa

I am going to graduate in 6 years from a 4 year major (Applied Mathematics) due to health reasons (diabetes, depression etc.)

I passed 70 credits so far, with 79 more to go. Average of my 70 credits is 2.45 (22 CC/2.0 and 16 DC/1.5 due to low performance) and to achieve something over 3.0, rest should be 3.5 on average and maximum GPA I can reach is 3.25 if all 79 credits are 4.0 on average.

Not impossible now that I am all better and more organized, it just stress me out to think it is all over if I don't do perfect, and I really want to do Masters especially abroad (I am in Turkey)

I am in a good school, have a good relation with teachers and do well when I apply myself to classes.

Problem is all I hear is "3.0 or nothing" for Masters in a good place.

If it is essential I can try to increase my GPA even more by taking classes next years first semester (I will likely pass all first semester classes this year but second semester will be left) for classes I passed with lower grades (1.5-2.0)

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate of: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/is-it-possible-to-get-into-a-good-masters-program-in-computer-science-with-a-3-3 , https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59332/are-masters-programs-generally-easier-to-get-into-than-phd?rq=1 , https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29003/trauma-affected-my-grades-while-in-undergrad-how-will-it-affect-me-getting-into

Comment: @tonysdg 2 of those questions are asked by people with over 3.0, which is not my case, but I will checkout the third one, thanks.

Comment: I cannot image how this question can be answered. You want someone to guarantee your acceptance with GPA under 3.0? That is absurd. You want someone to guarantee your rejection from every possible school due to GPA under 3.0? That is even more absurd. Acceptance in the math/science schools across the globe is not a sigmoid function from gpa.

Comment: @WestEast that is the point, I keep hearing overall GPA of 3.0 is mandatory to apply for Masters, I am asking to see if there is anything else I can do and if an increase in performance is also a factor despite overall GPA being low.

Comment: An international student with a sub-3.0 GPA stands essentially no chance of getting admission to a "good" graduate school abroad. There are just too many candidates with stronger applications. Doing better int he later years might help a bit, but you're going to need a lot of help to get in. Perhaps one of your faculty members can help you?